# Insert records to another table with trigger if row changes except one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

**Case**

I have two tables with following structures (I removed 34 other columns that were not related to question)

```
Table1
------
Id
LastAccessed
Data1
Data2

Table1_History
------
_Id
Action
Id
LastAccessed
Data1
Data2
```

Every time a user reads the record (with specific procedure) the `LastAccessed` timestamp will change.

I attached a trigger to `Table1` which copies the record to history table if `Data1` or `Data2` (or in my case any other column changes); However I don't want a copy or record in case `LastAccessed` changes.

Here is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGER!] 
   ON  TABLE1
   AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT UPDATE([LastAccessed]) BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [Table1_Hist](
                Action, Id, LastAccessed, Data1, Data2
            ) SELECT 
                'EDIT', Id, LastAccessed, Data1, Data2
            FROM deleted
        END ELSE BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [Table1_Hist](
                Action, Id, LastAccessed, Data1, Data2
            ) SELECT 
                'DELETE', Id, LastAccessed, Data1, Data2
            FROM deleted
        END
    END
END
```

This trigger will not copy row if LastAccessed and Data1 both change (which I want to). to solve this issue I can change the `IF` statement to

```
IF UPDATE(Id) OR UPDATE(Data1) OR UPDATE(Data2) ... BEGIN
```

In this case it will work as intended

**Question:**
As I have 34 columns in my table it is not easy to specify every column in `IF` statement.
Is there any easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully someone has a more elegant answer than this, but worst case you can generate that ugly IF statement for all 34 columns with a simple query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_id = 1 THEN 'IF ' ELSE 'OR ' END + 'UPDATE(' + name + ')' 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Table1]') 
        AND name <> 'LastUpdated'
    ORDER BY column_id
```

Then you can just cut-and-paste the results for your IF statement... not an elegant solution, but it's quicker than typing it all by hand.

Comment: Thank you bill, I wrote an application (in C#) that already does that. it is automatic, however the output is very big.I was hoping for a solution that look a little simpler

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGER!] 
   ON  TABLE1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Table1_Hist (
Action
Id
LastAccessed
Data1
Data2
)
SELECT 'UPDATE',d.ID,d.LastAccessed,d.Data1,d.Data2, etc., etc.
FROM DELETED d
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON d.id = i.id
WHERE 
COALESCE(d.data1,'') <> COALESCE(i.data1,'') OR
COALESCE(d.data2,'') <> COALESCE(i.data2,'') OR
<repeat for every attribute EXCEPT LastAccessed>
END
```

This will also work for inserts or updates of multiple rows, whereas your method would potentially insert rows where the data did not actually change.

Also, you want to have separate UPDATE and DELETE triggers because your query should just dump the full row set from DELETED in case of an actual DELETE.

Comment: Note that you can omit the COALESCE for any attribute that is defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your answer, but `<repeat for every attribute EXCEPT LastAccessed>` was the part that I was trying to avoid

Comment: There is no avoiding it, unfortunately :)  What I posted was the cleanest way of doing it while still maintaining the desired results.  The problem with UPDATE(colname) is that it will return true whether or not the data actually changed.